# Using class variables in SQL statements with $this->var

Tags: php, pdo, this, private

The script below processes form data and saves it to a sql table: Text fields and an image url. The image is also saved to the server. I have **two PDO connections** being executed. The first one (at the scripts beginning) uploads all the text fields. The row is then retrieved by $id=$conn->lastInsertId();  The second PDO connection (line 75) updates that row ($this->id) with the images url (variable $listing_img)

****This script runs to completion and echos all the json_encoded response data.****

**The second PDO does not function however (Line77)**, the value for the variable $listing_img does not get entered.

*I believe it's not working because the variable 'id' is not visible to the SQL statement as $this->id*

```
<?php
//process pdf file upload
if (isset($_FILES["flyer"]["name"]))
    ;
{
    $allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
    $tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
    $extensionf = end($tempf);
    if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf") && ($_FILES["flyer"]["size"] < 524288000) && in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) {

        if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) {
            //if file exists, delete the file on the server
            unlink("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
        }
        //move currrent pdf to the flyers folder
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"], "../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
        //Make url of pdf file
        $ad_link = "http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];

        //SQL statement 1, insert all form fields, file url and current date time
    } else {
        $ad_link = NULL;
    }
    require ('../dbcon2.php');
    //Connection 1
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO listings (title, address, lot_size, zoning, build_size, sale_price, lease_price, comment, transaction, ad_link, date_added) VALUES (:title, :address, :lot_size, :zoning, :build_size, :sale_price, :lease_price, :comment, :transaction, :ad_link, now())");
    //Bind
    $stmt -> bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':address', $_POST['address']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':lot_size', $_POST['lot_size']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':zoning', $_POST['zoning']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':build_size', $_POST['build_size']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':sale_price', $_POST['sale_price']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':lease_price', $_POST['lease_price']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':comment', $_POST['comment']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':transaction', $_POST['transaction']);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':ad_link', $ad_link);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $id = $conn -> lastInsertId();
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $lot_size = $_POST['lot_size'];
    $zoning = $_POST['zoning'];
    $build_size = $_POST['build_size'];
    $sale_price = $_POST['sale_price'];
    $lease_price = $_POST['lease_price'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $transaction = $_POST['transaction'];
    $conn = null;
}
//Create class
class CropAvatar {
    private $id;
    private $src;
    private $title;
    private $address;
    private $lot_size;
    private $zoning;
    private $build_size;
    private $sale_price;
    private $lease_price;
    private $comment;
    private $transaction;
    private $data;
    private $file;
    private $dst;
    private $type;
    private $extension;
    //location to save original image
    private $srcDir = '../0images/listimg/orig';
    //location to save cropped image
    private $dstDir = '../0images/listimg/mod';
    private $msg;
    //Add to consttruct
    function __construct($src, $data, $file, $id, $title, $address, $lot_size, $zoning, $build_size, $sale_price, $lease_price, $comment, $transaction) {
        $this -> setSrc($src);
        $this -> setData($data);
        $this -> setFile($file);
        $this -> setId($id);
        $this -> setTitle($title);
        $this -> setAddress($address);
        $this -> setLot_size($lot_size);
        $this -> setZoning($zoning);
        $this -> setBuild_size($build_size);
        $this -> setSale_price($sale_price);
        $this -> setLease_price($lease_price);
        $this -> setComment($comment);
        $this -> setTransaction($transaction);
        $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data, $this -> id, $this -> title, $this -> address, $this -> lot_size, $this -> zoning, $this -> build_size, $this -> sale_price, $this -> lease_price, $this -> comment, $this -> transaction);
    }

    public function __get($id) {
        if (property_exists($this, $id)) {
            return $this -> $id;
        }
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this -> id = $id;
    }

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this -> title = $title;
    }

    public function setAddress($address) {
        $this -> address = $address;
    }

    public function setLot_size($lot_size) {
        $this -> lot_size = $lot_size;
    }

    public function setZoning($zoning) {
        $this -> zoning = $zoning;
    }

    public function setBuild_size($build_size) {
        $this -> build_size = $build_size;
    }

    public function setSale_price($sale_price) {
        $this -> sale_price = $sale_price;
    }

    public function setLease_price($lease_price) {
        $this -> lease_price = $lease_price;
    }

    public function setComment($comment) {
        $this -> comment = $comment;
    }

    public function setTransaction($transaction) {
        $this -> transaction = $transaction;
    }

    //NNEED TO SET THE VARIABLES

    private function setSrc($src) {
        if (!empty($src)) {
            $type = exif_imagetype($src);
            if ($type) {
                $this -> src = $src;
                $this -> type = $type;
                $this -> extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                $this -> setDst();
            }
        }
    }

    private function setData($data) {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $this -> data = json_decode(stripslashes($data));
        }
    }

    private function setFile($file) {
        $errorCode = $file['error'];
        if ($errorCode === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $type = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);
            if ($type) {
                $dir = $this -> srcDir;
                if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                    mkdir($dir, 0777);
                }
                $currdate = date('YmdHis');
                $extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                $src = $dir . '/' . $currdate . $extension;
                if ($type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
                    if (file_exists($src)) {
                        unlink($src);
                    }
                    $result = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $src);
                    $listing_img = "http://www.website.com/0images/listimg/mod/" . $currdate . $extension;
                    if ($result) {
                        //Connection 2 - Update sql row according to row id with the url of cropped image
                        require ('../dbcon2.php');
                        $conn2 = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                        $conn2 -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                        $sql2 = "UPDATE listings SET listing_img=:listing_img WHERE id=:id";
                        $q = $conn2 -> prepare($sql2);
                        $q -> execute(array(':id' => $this -> id, ':listing_img' => $listing_img));
                        $this -> src = $src;
                        $this -> type = $type;
                        $this -> extension = $extension;
                        $this -> setDst();
                    } else {
                        $this -> msg = 'Failed to save image file';
                    }
                } else {
                    $this -> msg = 'Please upload image with the following types only: JPG, PNG, GIF';
                }
            } else {
                $this -> msg = 'Please upload image file';
            }
        } else {
            $this -> msg = $this -> codeToMessage($errorCode);
        }
    }

    private function setDst() {
        $dir = $this -> dstDir;
        if (!file_exists($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0777);
        }
        $this -> dst = $dir . '/' . date('YmdHis') . $this -> extension;
    }

    private function crop($src, $dst, $data) {
        if (!empty($src) && !empty($dst) && !empty($data)) {
            switch ($this -> type) {
                case IMAGETYPE_GIF :
                    $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                    break;
                case IMAGETYPE_JPEG :
                    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                    break;
                case IMAGETYPE_PNG :
                    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                    break;
            }
            if (!$src_img) {
                $this -> msg = "Failed to read the image file";
                return;
            }
            $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 220);
            $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $data -> x, $data -> y, 220, 220, $data -> width, $data -> height);
            if ($result) {
                switch ($this -> type) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF :
                        $result = imagegif($dst_img, $dst);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG :
                        $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG :
                        $result = imagepng($dst_img, $dst);
                        break;
                }

                if (!$result) {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to save the cropped image file";
                }
            } else {
                $this -> msg = "Failed to crop the image file";
            }

            imagedestroy($src_img);
            imagedestroy($dst_img);
        }
    }

    private function codeToMessage($code) {
        switch ($code) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE :
                $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE :
                $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL :
                $message = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE :
                $message = 'No file was uploaded';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR :
                $message = 'Missing a temporary folder';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE :
                $message = 'Failed to write file to disk';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION :
                $message = 'File upload stopped by extension';
                break;
            default :
                $message = 'Unknown upload error';
        }
        return $message;
    }

    public function getResult() {
        return !empty($this -> data) ? $this -> dst : $this -> src;
    }

    public function getMsg() {
        return $this -> msg;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this -> id;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this -> title;
    }

    public function getAddress() {
        return $this -> address;
    }

    public function getLot_size() {
        return $this -> lot_size;
    }

    public function getZoning() {
        return $this -> zoning;
    }

    public function getBuild_size() {
        return $this -> build_size;
    }

    public function getSale_price() {
        return $this -> sale_price;
    }

    public function getLease_price() {
        return $this -> lease_price;
    }

    public function getComment() {
        return $this -> comment;
    }

    public function getTransaction() {
        return $this -> transaction;
    }

}

$crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file'], $id, $title, $address, $lot_size, $zoning, $build_size, $sale_price, $lease_price, $comment, $transaction);
$response = array('state' => 200, 'message' => $crop -> getMsg(), 'result' => $crop -> getResult(), 'id' => $crop -> getId(), 'title' => $crop -> getTitle(), 'address' => $crop -> getAddress(), 'lot_size' => $crop -> getLot_size(), 'zoning' => $crop -> getZoning(), 'build_size' => $crop -> getBuild_size(), 'sale_price' => $crop -> getSale_price(), 'lease_price' => $crop -> getLease_price(), 'comment' => $crop -> getComment(), 'Transaction' => $crop -> getTransaction());

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Any recommendations on how to get the 2nd SQL statement to execute?

Besides a fix I'm trying to understand why $this->id is not pulling the id (if that's in fact the problem), when its echoing just fine in JSON?

Comment: You can't (directly) access variables from outside the class in an instance of a class.  That's why functions have the ability to pass in parameters...

Comment: @developerwjk how do i get id in there? Or do you see a better place to run the 2nd sql statement?

Comment: DOWNVOTER please state reason, thank you

Comment: On second look you are passing `$id` in to the constructor of `CropAvatar`, so you already knew what I said above. All I can say is this code is pretty messy. You should improve the indenting and define the class somewhere other than in the middle of the operation, and maybe making it easier to read would help you find the error.  Also, don't use the same variable names between the outside and inside of the class, as that might get confusing.  Like maybe put a prefix to class members, like `$m_id` rather than just `$id`.

Comment: @developerwjk thank you in advance, could you elaborate just a little on this:  "define the class somewhere other than in the middle of the operation"

Comment: The actual error is the db variables for servername, etc. are not visible inside the class.  You shouldn't be making a second PDO connection anyway. You should have passed `$conn` into the class and used it.

Comment: You could include the class with a `require` like you did dbcon2.php  At least you should define it before you begin the functional programming for this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE listings SET listing_img=$listing_img WHERE id=$this->id";
$q = $conn2->prepare($sql2); 
$q->execute($sql2); //Executing the sql string ????
```

from your first query I can tell that you know how to prepare, so do the same:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE listings SET listing_img=:listing_img WHERE id=:id";
$q = $conn2->prepare($sql2); 
$q->execute(array(':id'=>$this->id, ':listing_img'=>$listing_img));
```

Comment: I like this method but I'm getting a few errors...<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://www.website.com/0images/listimg/mod/20141212211339.jpeg WHERE id=NULL' at line 1' in /crop-avatar.php:178
Stack trace: it seems $q->execute(array(':id'=>$this->id)); returns a null value?

Comment: @Rhillz I forgot one of your params check now

Comment: Placing back ticks around '$listing_img' WHERE id=:id"; corrected the syntax problems but id is still null, i'm puzzled

Comment: @Rhillz is it the last insertid you need, why you have code on top of the class

Comment: no errors, but id is still null....   could this be hiding the value of my id?   $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data, $this -> id, $this -> title, $this -> address, $this -> lot_size);
    }   Approx line 32 right after the construct. Is this saying just use it in a crop function. I promise this last ? I'm really trying to get my head around php visibility

Comment: @Rhillz id is a private property you need to use getter and setter method to access it. Is your insert successful

Comment: @Rhillz what is `$this -> crop()` function it is not defined in that class

Comment: it's needed later on. I went ahead and posted the entire script above in question. crop is a function at ~ line 208. I was wondering if me putting id in the crop function within the construct RESTRICTS it just to that function. I really think you are on the right direction with using __get I'm just trying to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66789/discussion-between-meda-and-rhillz).

Answer (score 1):

This is your first problem:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE listings SET listing_img=$listing_img WHERE id=$this->id";
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`$listing_img` is a string, so without quotes, your sql statement will fail.

Why are you not using a prepared statement here like you do in your first sql statement? That would solve all your problems.

Also note that the `execute()` method takes an array with the parameters to bind as its first parameter (if you have not bound the variables manually). You are sending your sql string and apart from the fact that that is not necessary, it will probably lead to errors as well.

By the way, you can also easily share your PDO connection so that you only need one.

Comment: if I bind $q->bindParam(':id', $this->id); then in sql I should WHERE id=":id", as :id is now also a string?  would you have a reference for sharing PDO connections (when one is outside of the class, and the other inside). Thank you so much for your help by the way

Comment: @Rhillz No, take a look at your first sql statement, you don't use quotes anywhere when you bind variables. And you can send the PDO connection as a parameter to for example your constructor and set it there as a class variable.